# Glue between X3DH and Double-Ratchet

Tags: signal-protocol

While studying Signal and more particulartly X3DH and Double-Ratchet one particular apsect seems unspoken or not really documented.  X3DH provides a shared secret however Double-Ratchet needs a shared secret and a public key.

In the Double-Ratchet documentation they say that either Alice can be the only Double-Ratchet initiator either Bob can be the iniatiator too if the shared secret (of X3DH) is used as the first chain key of the Double-Ratchet.

I place my study in a world where Alice and Bob can initiate the Double-Ratchet. As such they use the shared secret as their initial chain key. However against a passive adversary, if the X3DH shared secret has been compromised then  the adversary will be able to read the first and second message of the Double-Ratchet (not more because of state healing). As such:

First and foremost, have I missed something ?

Are there studies on this particular aspect ?

Comment: Only the first sending message(s) can be read. The first receiving message(s) will have ratchet initialised by sender's ratchet public key.